# NVidia screen config

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg, lightdm

How do I restore the display config to the one I got during installation?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with dual nvidia gtx 570 connected to two screens.

When I installed ubuntu at first I ran 13.10 and everything worked right out of the box, marvelous. Then I upgraded to 14.04 and after the first boot I was greeted with a single dialog window with something along the lines of "Could not detect your graphics settings". But after I rebooted they disappeared, but today they came back and didn't go away no matter the number of reboots.

So I decided to try and fix them by installing the xorg-edgers ppa(just added the ppa, then update and upgrade). Now I never get that "Could not detect"-dialog, lightdm always launches but only one screen activates, the resolution is terrible and after login Unity never launches at all.

I've tried `sudo nvidia-settings` and `sudo nvidia-xorg` and restarting lightdm but neither seems to restore it to how it was.

`ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended` tells me `driver: nvidia-337 - third-party free recommended`